# Generator of rational functions unchanged under $\sigma(X) = X + 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

> Let $L = K(X)$ be the field of rational functions over a field $K$ with characteristic $p > 0$, and let $\sigma \in \operatorname{Aut}_K(L)$ with $\sigma(X) = X + 1$.
>   Show that $G = \left<\sigma\right>$ is finite, and determine a generator of $L^G = \{ f \in L: \rho(f) = f$ for all $\rho \in G \}$ over $K$.

My solution so far: $G = \left<\sigma\right>$ is finite because char $(K) = p > 0$ and therefore $\sigma^p (X) = X + p = X $.

A rational function unchanged under $\sigma$ will also be unchanged under any $\sigma^n$, so we don't have to worry about powers of $\sigma$ I think.

Any ideas for finding a generator? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$L^G=K(X^p-X)$. To prove this use that $[L:L^G]=p$, $[L:K(X^p-X)]=p$ and $K(X^p-X)\subseteq L^G$.

Comment: I see why that would work, but why exactly is $[L:K(X^p - X)] = p$ true? Thanks again.

Comment: @MrReese Because the minimal polynomial of $X$ over $K(X^p-X)$ is $Y^p-Y-(X^p-X)$.